# How many morphemes are there in "assertion"?

Tags: linguistics, morphology

Is it "a+sert+tion" or "assert+tion"? I found [an article](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=assertion) here that says its the former, but the answer key of the quiz which this question is in says otherwise, Help?

Comment: For speakers who know the verb _assert_ and relate it to _assertion_, two. For speakers who don't, one. There may be people who parse it _a+sert+ tion_, but I've never encountered any.

Comment: 1. That's not an article; it's an Etymology Online entry. 2. "adser" (if that's even a Latin word) is not an _English_ word. I'd say the English word "assert" has one morpheme, and "assertion" probably has two.